# S3 pre signed url without path

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, boto

I need a to have a way of letting a client upload data to S3 without showing them the full location (path) of the file. Is that something doable with AWS S3 pre-signed URL?

I'm using boto3 as such

```
s3.client.generate_presigned_url(
  ClientMethod='put_object', 
  ExpiresIn=7200,
  Params={'Bucket': BUCKET, 'Key': name}
)
```

But the outcome will be:

`https://s3.amazonaws.com/MY_BUCKET/upload/xxxx-xxxx/file-name.bin?AWSAccessKeyId=XXXX&Signature=XXXX&Expires=XXXX`

I need something like that won't show the Key name in the path (`/upload/xxxx-xxxx/file-name.bin`).

What other solutions do I have if not the pre-signed url?

Comment: I'm just throwing an idea: you could have a trivial Lambda function that gets triggered on upload and then moves/renames the uploaded object.

Comment: @AlexanderAzarov Exactly what I'm trying to avoid, but I suppose I could do it

Comment: Lambda@edge might be useful here.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you do not want them to see the path/key? Knowing it doesn't give them any additional access.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I know, but because of some legacy code, that path is open on another application. Until we can fully migrate customers and whatnot there is a need to hide it.

Answer (score 4):

I believe best way is distributing files with AWS Cloudfront. You can set the origin of the Cloudfront distribution to `MY_BUCKET.s3.amazonaws.com`. It is also possible to use subfolders like `MY_BUCKET.s3.amazonaws.com/upload` as origin.

Cloudfront will serve your files within S3 origin with generated CDN endpoint domain or it is possible to set and use custom domain as well.

https://d111111abcdef8.cloudfront.net/upload/xxxx-xxxx/file-name.bin
https://uploads.example.com/upload/xxxx-xxxx/file-name.bin

if you use subfolder as origin:

https://uploads.example.com/xxxx-xxxx/file-name.bin

---

More info on setting S3 Bucket as origin on Cloudfront: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/DownloadDistS3AndCustomOrigins.html#concept_S3Origin

More info on using directory paths of S3 Bucket as origin: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2014/12/16/amazon-cloudfront-now-allows-directory-path-as-origin-name/

More info on Custom URLs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html

Comment: Of course I use cloudfront for interfacing with S3, and that doesn't help with my upload problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

This isn’t a complete answer, but it’s too long to be a comment.

I think you should be able to use API Gateway as a proxy for S3 to hide the path. You can still use pre-signed urls, but you might need to create pre-signed API Gateway urls rather than pre-signed S3 urls. I’ve never done it myself—nor will I be able to try it out in near future—but I’ll do my best to lay out how I think it’s done, and maybe someone else can try it and write up a more complete answer.

First, we need to set up an API gateway endpoint that will act as a proxy to S3.

AWS has a very thorough write-up on [how to make a general proxy for S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html), and I think you can make your custom endpoint point to a specific bucket and folder in S3 by modifying the PathOverride of the proxy.  If you look at the screenshot of the PathOverrides in [this section](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html#api-items-in-folder-as-s3-objects-in-bucket) of the AWS documentation, you can see they have set the path override to `{bucket}/{object}`, but I think you could set the PathOverride to `mySecretBucket/my/secret/folder/{object}`, and then update the path mappings appropriately.

Next, you need to be able to use pre-signed urls with this proxy. There’s two ways you *might* be able to do this.

The first thing that might work is making the url signature pass through API Gateway to S3. I know it’s possible to map query parameters in a similar way to path parameters. You may need to perform some url encoding on the pre-signed URL’s signature param to make it work—I’m not entirely sure.

The other option is to allow Api Gateway to always write to S3, and require a signed request for calling your proxy endpoint. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54029564/how-to-create-presigned-url-for-aws-gateway-api) has a pretty detailed answer that looks to me like it should work.

Again, I know this isn’t a complete answer, and I haven’t tried to verify that this works, but hopefully someone can start with this and get to a complete answer for your question.

Comment: I'm not satisfied, but at least you provided something other than lambda which seems reasonable. I am giving you the bounty but leaving the question open for now

Comment: That’s fair. It’s not a very satisfying solution. It seems like it should be a pretty straightforward feature for AWS to add obfuscated pre-signed links; I don’t know why they don’t support it.